# Copying over existing DLLs in ASP.NET MVC Production Web Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, updating

I have worked with ASP.NET MVC web projects for quite some time for very small personal projects. In my personal projects I've usually subdivided my code into separate projects like XXX.Business, XXX.DataLayer, etc. which causes those to be generated in separate DLLs.

My company is now moving in that direction for some of its future projects. I've been asked about deployment of individual DLLs. In my personal projects, I've always just copied them into to the web server overwriting what was there. I pretty sure they worked immediately when I tested, but then I was probably the only user on my site at that time.

What is going to happen if we were to try the same thing in a busy production situation?

Comment: The application pool is recycled so you have a delay as the app is reloaded with the next request. You must also make sure the expected version and actual file versions match or update the web.config accordingly. Also do not change any of your external interfaces / namespaces. Frankly it is usually better to do a recompile of the solution and deploy the entire bin folder otherwise you might get unexpected errors (someone changed a method signature or name or namespace) and you will not know why that occurred unless you have very stringent change control.

Comment: Also if you deploy your app as a Web Deploy Package, all referenced dll in your solution are included

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Assuming I we deploy everything (such as a Web Deploy) at once, is this like taking a server out of rotation temporarily? One person keeps saying we have to "take down the web server," and I don't understand what that even means. Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm just not really familiar with big time production deployments.

Comment: @danny He means that if you have multiple production web servers and a load balancer that sits in front of those servers and routes traffic to them, then you should remove the web server you want to update from from the load balancer, then update that web server with the new software, then put it back into the load balancer's rotation.  You go through this process for each web server until they are all updated.